# Can Hibernate update two tables with one bean?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am working on a project using Hibernate and Spring; single screen, one bean, but two tables. I wanted to know if Hibernate can update *two* MySQL tables within a single call?

If so, how do I code the following bean (model) to update two tables!

User name and password is in the user table.
User name and enabled is in the rights table.

Below is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Long userId;  // in user and rights tables!

    @NotEmpty(message = "User name must not be blank.")
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String username; // in user table

    @NotEmpty(message = "Password must not be blank.")
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password; // in user table

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Long enabled; // in rights table
}
```

Comment: Why do the rights are located in a different table if they belong to the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate-Spring ; One Screen, One Bean but two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588546/hibernate-spring-one-screen-one-bean-but-two-tables)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use a [@SecondaryTable](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2235) annotation and specify the name of that table in appropriate @Column annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@SecondaryTable(name="rights", pkJoinColumns=
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="userid")
)
public class User {

...

@Column(name = "enabled", table="rights")
private Long enabled; // in rights table
```

Comment: thanks for the information can I please ask where did you find this? I been looking for days...  thanks

Comment: @Stuttering - it's in Hibernate Annotations manual (there's a link in my answer above); it's also in Hibernate Core manual (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e6906) chapter 5.1.6.5, though it's rather confusingly put in "inheritance" section in there.

Comment: Or if you use more than two tables, we may use the  @SecondaryTables annotation more than once for the same entity (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot do this. In some sense, ORM is about mapping one row to one object. The best you can do is use a SQL view to create a read-only structure corresponding to this bean. That would allow you to query your data into the structure you've devised, but you would not be able to do updates.

Answer (score 0):

IF you require it to be in a different table, do something like this

```
class User {
    Long userid;
    String username; // why both a userid and a username?
    String password;
    Rights rights;
}

class Rights {
    boolean enabled;
    boolean canModerate;
    int maxSomething;
    // other rights here
}
```

Comment: You'd have to add your annotations yourself, but the idea is that instead of having members in one class referenced in a different table, it would be better for code clarity to have a separate class for your Rights. If your rights are simple enough, you don't even need to associate your userid with them.